# Can't save OpenXML file made on server to clients local folder "Access Denied"

Tags: c#, excel, permission-denied, access-denied

I'm using ASP.Net 4.7 / C# / OpenXML in a web application.

I'm trying a new way to make an Excel document from a GridView as my current code outputs a file that is not exactly an Excel file as Windows complains on opening it, even though its called .XLS,

```
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment;filename=" + filename + ".xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.Write(style);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
```

which is not ideal. My current way saves a file fine to my downloads folder. OpenXML is a much neater way to make my Excel document (in XLSX format) if it only saved.

I'm using the simply excellent code found here (with some modifications of my own) https://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/CSharp/ExportToExcel.htm

My issue is for the life of me I cannot get past the "Access to Path '..' denied" issue I'm seeing.

I can save the Excel document to various folders on my local PC when running the code on my Local PC. I can save the Excel file to a folder on the server when running the website code on the server, but I can't make the file on the server and save to my client PC.

I understand its a permissions things, but in this area I'm a total noob.

In the last three days I've tried:

- Implemented numerous was to set permissions on my local folders "C:\temp", "C:\username\downloads", etc.
- Activated IIS7.
- Read the OpenXML documentation.
- Searched Google, Bing and YouTube and still no nearer to saving my file.

Curiously, I've found that if I code the path to be "C:\Users\Public\Downloads\" then it says its successful but no file appears??

I can post code if required but I'm not sure it's the code that's the issue here.

An help or links in the right direction appreciated.

Comment: `xls` is *NOT* an OpenXML format. Only `xlsx`. The content type is wrong either. None of these would cause the error though. You *can't* control what the *client's browser* will do. You can send a file to the browser with a filename but it's up to the *end user* to save it either to the browser's Download folder or another one

Comment: Picture for a minute what life would be like if *any random website you visited* was able to drop any files it wanted to onto your own machine. Would you really like to experience that?

Comment: Thanks for your reply's but maybe I need to add more detail. I'm not trying to make an XLS document, that's what I get with my current way of doing it, but what I get with the OpenXML is a nice XLSX document. I'm aware of security risks and agree we couldn't have any Tom, Dick or Harry dropping files on our PC's but I can currently, using my original code get it to download a file to my PC using my c# code, but not with the OpenXML code I can't.

Comment: I will add, i'm not after it happening automatically, the user must instigate the creation of said file and action the download.

Comment: You haven't posted any OpenXML code. What you posted doesn't show any attempt to create an `xls` file either, it just sends a string content to the server. People can't help you with code problems when you don't post the actual code

Comment: As for generating `xlsx` documents you'll find a *lot* of duplicates. With EPPlus all you'd need to creatre an `xlsx` file would be to load the data into it eg with `sheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection(someList)` and then save the package to the output stream with `package.Save(Response.Output)`.

Comment: Are you using webforms? ASP.NET MVC? Web API? Core? There are duplicates for each of these cases which show how to save to the stream directly. That works for small files.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, I found a way to do it where I compile the file on the server and save the file to a folder on the server, then update a hyperlink to allow downloading my new file. Job done. This Question can be closed / deleted.